# Expect not working as expected

Tags: linux, bash, scripting, automation, expect

EDIT: So ultimately what I ended up doing here is running it straight in a mysql.expect script. Any variables that need to be updated would be replaced via sed in standard bash script used to launch mysql.expect.

I have a bash script that runs expect, and automates the MySQL installation process, as you can see [here](http://pastebin.com/mtA7Ncxb). The reason expect needs to be called in this script is to source local bash variables, so I can't just run it via expect, but rather it needs to be called it as follows:

```
if [ catch "spawn /bin/bash ./mysql.sh" error ] {

   puts "Could not spawn mysql.sh $error"

}
```

I know this works, because there's another script I have called "test.sh" that does the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
source ./myvars.rc

echo "CONNECTED" >> "./out.html"

echo "$MYVARIABLE" >> "./out.html"
```

This works fine, the variable is correctly added to out.html. The mysql.sh script works when called directly, but not through expect, and there are no errors. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Whether the spawned process for mysql_installation is started running when u ran this script via expect? Still didnt get a clue, then add `-d` flag with expect and see the debug information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not an expect expert, but you may have a syntax error in the `spawn` command. This seems to work:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

if { [ catch {spawn /bin/bash ./mysql.sh} error ] } {  
   puts "Could not spawn mysql.sh $error"
}
# This is the important part
interact
```

<s>`catch` returns 0 (OK) if your command succeeds. You were seeing "success" because it really errored out, but you were testing the other condition.</s>

So, I did some more testing and updated that a bit. You don't want the `!` there, but you do want the `interact`. Once you spawn something with `expect`, you want to either use `expect` to process the output, or if there is none to process, just let the script run with `interact`.

The interesting thing is that if you use `/bin/bash ./mysql.sh` without `interact`, this will just do nothing but not actually run the script. If you use just `./mysql.sh`, it will hang. I assume there is something with standard in/out that happens differently between the two.

Anyway, I hope this helps and actually solve your problem. Extra added stuff because I'm geeking out here -- you probably want `exec` instead of `spawn` if you don't want to interact with your script:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

if { [ catch {puts [exec /bin/bash ./mysql.sh]} error ] } {
   puts "Could not spawn mysql.sh $error"
}
```

The `puts` is there because otherwise you will lose the output of the script. If you don't care about the output, you can use:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

if { [ catch {exec /bin/bash ./mysql.sh} error ] } {
   puts "Could not spawn mysql.sh $error"
}
```

Comment: Thanks zerodiff, it's at least showing an error now which is progress ("could not spawn mysql.sh").